# What's the difference between "default" and "default-push" in TortoiseHg Settings > Commit?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

In TortoiseHg's settings, I can set "push after commit" to `unspecified`, `default`, or `default-push`. I understand `unspecified`, but what's the difference between `default` and `default-push`?

I did my Googling, but couldn't find an explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@example.com/path1
default-push = ssh://hg@example.com/path2
```

then

```
hg pull
hg push
```

do not refer to the same repo.